# Why EJB need to implement serializable interface?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serialization, ejb

Is there any reason why EJB classes need to be serializable?
I've heard it has something to do with the fact that RMI is being used under the hood. I know how RMI (remote method invocation) works, there's a remote object registered on the server side and only the stub of remote object is sent to the client, **not** the whole object.

So in RMI applications the methods of remote object need to take arguments and return values that are serializable, as they are being sent over the network, but not the remote object itself.

Comment: All EJB methods arguments and return values must be serializable. The easiest way to do this is to make sure all your classes implement java.io.Serializable.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, but I was asking if EJB itself needs to implement serializable.

Comment: EntityBean, MessageDrivenBean, SessionBean : All are extending EnterpriseBean which is Serializable.

Comment: I don't get it. You said all EJB methods arguments and return values must be serializable. Yes, I agree with that. But I'm asking if EJB classes need to be serializable AS WELL? If yes, why? The fact that my class implements serializable doesn't make it automatically return serializable objects or receive serializable arguments in its methods.

Comment: Since EJB meant for distributed application, the framework itself made these beans Serializable so that activation & passivation of beans can be taken care by persisting and retrieving the state.

Answer (score 13):

The reason that the old J2EE style EJBS that implement [javax.ejb.EntityBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/EntityBean.html), [javax.ejb.SessionBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/SessionBean.html) and [javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/MessageDrivenBean.html) should be serializable is historical. The original [javax.ejb.EnterpriseBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/EnterpriseBean.html) interface that these extend happens to itself extend [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). In the very early EJB days it was thought that this was needed to facilitate moving beans between JVMs.

All practical reasons for EJBs to *actually* implement Serializable disappeared by the time that the EJB 2.0 specification was published.

The introduction of EJB 3 removed the requirement for any of these interfaces (and subsequently java.io.Serializable) to be implemented.

No EJB specification since EJB 2.0 has specified that EJBs must be serializable. This has only been implicit because of the interface inheritance.

The implicit requirement disappears altogether with EJB 3.x.

Comment: As a side note the stateful EJB's properties (state) should be serializable since the stateful EJB can be passivated.

Comment: An Entity bean can be cached. Should It also implement Serializable?

Comment: @MaxG are you asking about javax.ejb.EntityBeans or javax.persistence.Entity beans? In the former case some implementations would cache the state of the bean rather then the bean itself. In the latter modern JPA case entity beans are expected to implement Serializable if they are running in an environment that copies/moves instances between JVM instances.